# ReactNative Android BroadcastReceiver Intent called multiple times

Tags: android, react-native

I am writing module that sends messages. Module I am working on creates intent and upon message received status emits event to RN:

Messages are sent correctly and event is emitted to RN, but on each consequent call, it triggers for all previously sent messages. So for first invoke it is called once, for the second twice and so on.

Here is what I use to broadcast to RN:

```
private void sendEvent(String messageId) {
        WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
        params.putString("id", messageId);
        this.reactContext
                .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                .emit("info", params);
    }
```

Here is how I am invoking the intent:

```
Random generator = new Random();

Intent sentIntent = new Intent(SENT);
sentIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(reactContext, generator.nextInt(),
                sentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


reactContext.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    sendEvent(messageId);
    }
}, new IntentFilter(SENT));
```

As you can see I am already trying to set flags that would not use the Intent after original call.
How can I make it to perform the intent once and upon sending/receiving of message cancel any future calls?

Comment: It looks like you're registering a new Receiver instance every time you send, but you're not unregistering them anywhere, so each subsequent message after the first is going to fire the Receiver for each one registered before it. You could just `unregisterReceiver(this)` in `onReceive()`, but that's a rather naive approach. Ideally, you'd attach some extra to the `Intent` to make sure you're unregistering the right one. Alternatively, you could register a single Receiver instance before all of your sends, and only unregister it when all sends are complete.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me a lot! I put as a filter name id of the message I am interested in. Then upon delivery report received I am unsubscribing with unregisterReceiver. Can you please put it as an answer? I'd like you to get some credit for it. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's another option. I'd not thought of that one. Nice. I'll put together an answer here in a little bit. Thanks. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BroadcastReceiver` instances will remain registered until you explicitly unregister them (or the registering `Context` is destroyed). In this case, you're creating and registering a new instance for each send, but never unregistering any of them. Since the broadcast `Intent` is always the same, after the first message, each subsequent message is going to fire not only its own newly registered instance, but also each instance registered previously.

There are a few different solutions for this.

- Registering only a single Receiver instance once, before any sends begin, and unregistering it after they're all complete. The particular message results could then be distinguished by extras on the `Intent`. If implementing this option, be sure that distinct `PendingIntent`s are created for each, by specifying a unique `requestCode` – the second argument in `getBroadcast()` – for each one.
- Continue registering a new instance for each send, and unregister it in `onReceive()`. An extra on the `Intent` can be used here also, to ensure that the correct instance is acting on a given broadcast, and is appropriately unregistered afterwards. Again, be sure that distinct `PendingIntent`s are used each time.
- As mentioned by the OP, similar to the second approach, continue using separate instances for each send, but use a different action `String` for each; e.g., by appending an ID to a base action. As the `Intent`s will then be inherently unequal, the `PendingIntent`s will already be distinct, and the unique `requestCode` isn't necessary.

Comment: Hi Mike, Its not part of the question but can we register two receivers with same react context for example 
 IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
 reactContext.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
 IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ANOTHER_ACTION);
 reactContext.registerReceiver(mReceiver2, filter2);